# Program that depends on the next input character?

Tags: c, char, scanf

Say I have an input string from `stdin`:

```
(5(4(11(7()())(2()()))()) (8(13()())(4()(1()()))))
```

Given that I've read a character `(`, there might be two possibilities:

1. An integer `int d`. (notice that `d` might consists of more than one character. e.g. the `13` in above)
2. The close parenthesis `)`

I need to do different task based on each case:

- if it's integer then I need to read it into `d`.
- if it's `)` then I will do some calculation and discard it.

Also, there might be arbitrary number of spaces or newlines between any visible characters in the input, so how can I know the next visible character(s) is integer or a `)`?

Comment: Use a one character buffer and delay the action

Comment: @klutt: Could you show it by code? If the next characters are `13` and I use the buffer you said, the integer is broken into `1`(read) and `3`(un-read), which I think might complicate my program.

Comment: I think you could use the `ungetc` function to do this. Puts one character back into the stream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `scanf`. It tells you whether a conversion could be made. If not, the next scan will re-scan the same input. So:

```
for (;;) {
    int d;
    int res = scanf("%d", &d);          // try a number
    
    if (res == EOF) break;              // end of input
    
    if (res == 1) {                     // yup, it's a number
        printf("int %d\n", d);
    } else {                            // nope, it's a char
        char c;
        
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        printf("char '%c'\n", c);
    }        
}
```

Comment: I just said there must be someone who will know a clean idea... +1

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to parse this string and trigger some actions on the various tokens found, a trivial hand-made lexical-scanner could ease.

The `%n` format is very convenient to skip an integer once detected.

note: to obtain the input string from `stdin`, just use `fgets()`.
If it stands on multiple lines (as added in the edit) just repeat the loop in `main()` for each new input line.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef enum {TK_ERROR, TK_OPEN, TK_CLOSE, TK_INT, TK_END} Token;

Token
scan(const char **input,
     int *value)
{
  const char *p=*input;
  for(char c=*p; c!='\0'; c=*(++p))
  {
    if(isspace(c))
    {
      continue; // nothing more to be done
    }
    if(c=='(')
    {
      *input=p+1;
      return TK_OPEN;
    }
    if(c==')')
    {
      *input=p+1;
      return TK_CLOSE;
    }
    int pos=-1;
    sscanf(p, "%d%n", value, &pos);
    if(pos!=-1)
    {
      *input=p+pos;
      return TK_INT;
    }
    return TK_ERROR;
  }
  return TK_END;
}

int
main(void)
{
  const char *input="(5(4(11(7()())(2()()))()) (8(13()())(4()(1()()))))";
  const char *current=input;
  int depth=0;
  for(bool stop=false; !stop;)
  {
    int value=-1;
    switch(scan(&current, &value))
    {
      case TK_ERROR:
      {
        printf("unexpected char <%c>\n", *current);
        ++current; // skip this char
        break;
      }
      case TK_OPEN:
      {
        ++depth;
        printf("OPEN depth=%d\n", depth);
        break;
      }
      case TK_CLOSE:
      {
        printf("CLOSE depth=%d\n", depth);
        --depth;
        break;
      }
      case TK_INT:
      {
        printf("INT %d depth=%d\n", value, depth);
        break;
      }
      case TK_END:
      {
        stop=true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, +1, I didn't know about `%n`. You also made a very decent comment, very helpful!